# Before focal point, the locally distance function is smooth

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm reading Eschenburg's paper Local convexity and nonnegative curvature — Gromov's proof of the sphere theorem recently. And I meet a little question: In the proof of Lemma 7.4, He let $d$ be the signed distance function of $B_{\delta}(y(s))\cap y(S)$ for $p=y(s)$ and let $f=d+\frac{\epsilon}{2}d^2$, where $y:S\to M$ is an $\epsilon$-convex immersion and $\delta$ such that $y|_{y^{-1}(B_{\delta}(y(s)))}$ is an embedding. Then he concluded that $f$ is smooth on $\{|d|\leq r_1\}$, where $r_1$ is the focal distance of the whole hypersurface $y(S)$. I can't understand why the locally distance function $d$ is smooth in this domain.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a unit normal field $n$ to the surface $S$.
Consider the map $m\colon S\times \mathbb{R}\to M$ defined by $m\colon(p,t)\mapsto \exp_p(t\cdot n_p)$.

Note $m$ is smooth and locally injective in $S\times (-r_1,r_1)$.
Then argue as in the [Gauss lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(Riemannian_geometry)).

Comment: I think this can be understand as the index theorem for focal points?

Comment: @eulershi yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: But I'm still confused that the $\delta$ in locally injective domain can be made uniformly for all $s\in S$, though $S$ is compact.

Comment: @eulershi you can do it locally and cover the surface by finite number of good neighborhoods.